# How to open html & css document

Tags: html, document

I have a very stupid question.
If I write a website layout in a css file and other stuff in a html file. How can I open the html but with the css layout in it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `<link ... />` element.

Read about it here:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

---

Linking your stylesheet works by putting

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourcssfile.css" />
```

into the `<head>`-section of your HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Put `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./yourstyle.css" />` in your `<head>`.

Comment: And I should put these two document in one file, is that right?

Comment: @Lily Yep, though you can put in a different directory if you change the path (e.g. `../../stylefolder/style.css`). Just FYI, 'files' are generally known as directories and 'documents' as files when programming - that could cause confusion when asking about files :)